# React: Redirect to new page from FUNCTION not from COMPONENT (working with React Router)

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I have a function running using a setInterval timer.  Its purpose is to ask the server if the login/sessionID I have in local storage is still valid.  If the session has expired, I want to give an alert and route to the Login page.

I would normally use something like `this.props.history.push("/login")` to accomplish the redirect.  But this cannot be a Component; being run by setInterval, it must be a function.  The React-Router history.push option is not available outside of Components, AFAIK.  What would be my best alternative?

Here is the setInterval code that happens at Login:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('mycha_sessionID',returnData.data.sessionID)
let intervalID = setInterval(CheckSession,1*30*1000)
sessionStorage.setItem('intervalID',intervalID)
```

And the function code that will run every interval:

```
import {axiosGet} from "./AxiosCalls";
import {ClearSession} from "./ClearSession";

export function CheckSession() {
    // Call Wordpress to see if the current session ID is still valid
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('mycha_sessionID')) {
        axiosGet(sessionStorage.getItem('mycha_base_url')+"/wp-json/mycha/check-session")
            .then(res => {
                if ((false === res.data) || ("" === res.data)) {
                    ClearSession()
                    alert("Your login session has expired.  Please log in again before continuing.")
                    // Redirect to Login here
                }
            })
            .catch(err => alert(err));
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but why not just call 
`window.location.href = 'https://www.my-site.com/login'`

Comment: Thank you, Barryman.  I was defaulting to a React-ish way of dealing with the issue, not thinking of normal JS techniques.  I just tested, and this did seem to get past part of my problem.  I will test further to be sure I didn't create a new issue to replace it.  :-)

Comment: @Barryman9000, this just worked fine for me.  Thank you very much.

I did end up using ```window.location.pathname = '/login'``` instead of .href.  That lets the same code work whether running in my test or production environments without having to specify the base domain of the url.  :-)

Comment: Great! I added an answer so you can mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding, but why not just call 
`window.location.href = 'https://www.my-site.com/login'`